# ";+" in the start of a line in CLIPS

Tags: clips

This might be a newbie question, but I am new to CLIPS and in some source files I find that in the start of some lines. Could anyone explain what does it do to me? thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The ; character is used to begin a comment. All characters after the ; on the same line are ignored.